# How can I convert a list of 3-tuples into one 3-triple of lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, visual-studio-code, functional-programming, tuples

I am attempting to write a function called that takes a list of triples and produces a 3-tuple of three lists. For instance, the function called on  `[(a,b,c), (d, e, f), (g, h, i)]` should produce `([a,d,g], [b, e, j], [c, f, i])`.

I have this so far:

```
-- This gives the head of a 3-tuple
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (x, _, _) = x

unzipTriples :: [(a, b, c)] -> a
unzipTriples (x : y : z : xs) = (fst3 x : fst3 y : fst3 z, unzipTriples xs)
```

I thought this would create a list [a, d, g] and then add it to the 3-tuple and do the rest for the remaining list. How can I improve this wrong function?

Comment: Let's think this through. First of all, what are the types of `x`, `y`, and `z`? Why do you want to get the first 3 elements from the input list? Also, what should the type of `unzipTriples` be? You described it in words already. What is that in Haskell syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `(x : y : z : xs)` in `unzipTriples (x : y : z : xs) = …` will take the first three elements of the list, so then `x`, `y` and `z` are 3-tuples. But you thus would limit yourself to processing lists with three or more elements.

What you can do is use `map` and thus work with:

```
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (a, _, _) = a

snd3 :: (a, b, c) -> b
snd3 (_, b, _) = b

thd3 :: (a, b, c) -> c
thd3 (_, _, c) = c

unzipTriples :: [(a, b, c)] -> ([a], [b], [c])
unzipTriples xs = (map fst3 xs, map snd3 xs, map thd3 xs)
```

But it is probably more elegant, and will consume less memory when you pattern match on the first item of the list, a 3-tuple, and then recurse on the tail of the list, so:

```
unzipTriples :: [(a, b, c)] -> ([a], [b], [c])
unzipTriples [] = ([], [], [])
unzipTriples ((a, b, c):xs) = (a:as, b:bs, c:cs)
    where ~(as, bs, cs) = unzipTriples xs
```

You can convert this into an expression with [**`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr), I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: AFAIK, `where ~(as, bs, cs) = ...` is equivalent to `where (as, bs, cs) = ...`. Let and where patterns are implicitly lazy.